# Error when trying to rosrun turtlebot_dashboard. Any ideas?

Tags: ros, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm trying to set up my Turtlebot for the first time.
I'm following the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/TurtleBot%20Bringup and everything is successful until the following:

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~/ros/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/upstart$ rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard&
[2] 19832
turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~/ros/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup/upstart$ [rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/turtlebot/ros_workspace
[rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/turtlebot/ROS/rosjava
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/turtlebot/ros/turtlebot_viz/turtlebot_dashboard/scripts/turtlebot_dashboard", line 50, in <module>
    import turtlebot_dashboard
  File "/home/turtlebot/ros/turtlebot_viz/turtlebot_dashboard/src/turtlebot_dashboard/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from turtlebot_frame import *
  File "/home/turtlebot/ros/turtlebot_viz/turtlebot_dashboard/src/turtlebot_dashboard/turtlebot_frame.py", line 40, in <module>
    import rxtools.cppwidgets as rxtools
  File "/home/turtlebot/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/cppwidgets.py", line 34, in <module>
    from rxtoolscpp import *
ImportError: No module named rxtoolscpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30640/error-when-trying-to-rosrun-turtlebot_dashboard.-any-ideas?/) by [unine_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2064/unine_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there could be a problem with the way you installed ROS. Did you do a source based installation or apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot-viz?

Check that $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is set to /opt/ros/electric/stacks and also to your workspace.

Add the line

> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/electric/stacks:(your_path)

to your .bashrc file

replace (your_path) with ~/ros_workspace if your ros_workspace directory is in your home directory.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1